# Unable to model bind a collection within a view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view like so:

```
@model Foo

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FooName);

@{
  int counter = -1;
  }
@foreach(var bar in Model.Bars)
{
  counter++;
  <tr>
    <td><span name = "Bars[@counter].BarName">@bar.BarName</span></td>
  </tr>
}
```

where:

```
class Foo
{
  public string FooName { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
  public string BarName { get; set; }
}
```

Even though my view has it right, when I post back the `Foo`, though, it doesn't post back its `Bars`.

```
public ActionResult DoStuffWithFoo(Foo foo)
{
  Debug.Assert(foo.Bars != null); // fails
}
```

I have omitted the unnecessary and obvious parts from this question such as the mark up of a table.

Comment: A `span` is not a form control. You need an `<input>`. And use a `for` loop - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bars[i].BarName) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that on `form` post you post only values in `inputs` so you should to something like this:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model.Bars[i].BarName)</span></td>
  </tr>
}
```

`Html.TextBoxFor` helper create `input` that you can post to controller.

Comment: Thank you. What if I do not want a textbox. Is there like a read-only control that I can just display and also post-back? I know I can disable the textbox but still, I am curious. Does the html `<label>` control postback?

Comment: you always can use `Html.HiddenFor()` for this purpose

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, You can use `@Html.HiddenFor()` but what is the point of sending all that data to the client and then posting it all back again unchanged. Just get the collection again in the controller if you need it

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know I can do that. It's less performance intensive to just post the data back. It's trading a little bit of bandwidth for CPU time because that data was gotten from a lot of joins.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 then create hidden fields is your way =)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, Depends on how much data, and you can always use `Session`. But you are opening yourself up to over-posting attacks